# Определить сигнатуру функции

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Как в C++ определить сигнатуру функции, переданной в шаблон другой функции?
Делаю так:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename S>
struct Signature;

template<typename R, typename ...Args>
struct Signature<R(Args...)> {
    using RetType = R;

    using Arguments = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template<typename Func>
void test(Func f) {
    using Sig = Signature<Func>;
    Sig s; //Error: Sig<Func> - undefined struct
}

double square(double x) { return x * x; }

int main() {
    using Sig = Signature<decltype(square)>;
    Sig s; //ok
    test(square);
}
```

Вот что меня смутило в логе компиляции:

```
error C2079: 's' uses undefined struct 'Signature<Func>'
with
[
    Func=double (__cdecl *)(double)
]
```

Появилось `(__cdecl *)`. Что оно вообще означает, и как тогда определить сигнатуру в test(Func f)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Надо добавить специализацию для указателя на функцию:

```
template<typename R, typename ...Args>
struct Signature<R ( * )(Args...)> {
    using RetType = R;

    using Arguments = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

Это нужно потому, что после передачи функции в качестве параметра в `test` она неявно преобразуется в указатель и тип `Func` будет на самом деле указателем на функцию.

Comment: Реально ли определить сигнатуру лямбды, если она захватывает что-либо?

Comment: @EgorMoroz Захватывание лямбдой чего-либо не влияет на ее сигнатуру.